# AppMaker error say "The instance must be a 2nd generation SQL database" but it is a 2nd gen

Tags: google-app-maker

AppMaker gives this error: "The default Google Cloud SQL instance is not setup properly. Please ask a G Suite administrator to check the Google Cloud SQL configuration for your domain. (Reason: App Maker is unable to verify the default Google Cloud SQL instance. The instance must be a 2nd generation SQL database.)"

But the SQL database is a 2nd generation
ALF-experiments instances:
Instance ID     Type    High availability   Location    Labels
 sgialfmysql    MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7       us-central1-a

Connected as the default in admin console
Google Cloud SQL instance setting
Enter the Google Cloud SQL instance connection name to use with App Maker:
alf-experiments:us-central1:sgialfmysql

I have made multiple Cloud instances under multiple project but none seem to be able to connect. I have reviewed the documentation several times to verify that GCP and Cloud SQL are set correctly and they are.

Comment: After connecting with GCP help, they tell me: "After a quick research I found that your issue is related merely to App Maker, which unfortunately Out of my scope of expertise."

Comment: You should get in contact with the G Suite support team and ask for the API team. They should help you with this matter. https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en